# Rails restrict upload filetype to .xls only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wish to upload an excel sheet from the view but only excel 2003 workbooks should be accepted.
However, my attempt is not working.

This is my current implementations;

in the view

```
<%= file_field_tag :contact_file %>
```

and the controller;

```
if File.extname( params[:contact_file] ) == 'xls'
      @list = @current_user.lists.build(params[:list])
      @counter =0
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do |transaction|
        if @list.save
          if params[:contact_file]
            ap params[:contact_file]
            oo = Spreadsheet.open(params[:contact_file].path).worksheet(0)
            1.upto(oo.last_row_index) do |line|
              @counter+=1
              row = oo.row(line)
              name = row[0]
              phone_number = row[1].to_i.to_s
              new_contact = @current_user.contacts.build
              new_contact.phone_number = phone_number
              new_contact.name = name
              ap new_contact
              if new_contact.valid?
                new_contact.save
                @list.contacts << new_contact
              else
                if not @errors
                  @errors ={}
                end
                @errors["#{@counter+1}"] = new_contact.errors
              end
            end
          end

          if @errors
            render action: 'new'
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
          end
          redirect_to @list, notice: 'List was successfully created.'
        else
          render action: 'new'
        end
      end
    else
      flash[:notice] ="Please upload the correct file-format. Upload MS-Excel 2003 workbooks (.xls files)"
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
```

what could be the problem because this line  `File.extname( params[:contact_file] ) == 'xls'`does not seem to work.

the request parameters look like this;

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tzwsIt6sPhEFEqwS6YraU7SYU+kEvAr1it33j8YzCPk=", "list"=>{"name"=>"acacia", "user_id"=>"1"}, "contact_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xd7ad3b8 @original_filename="NGOs.xlsx", @content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"contact_file\"; filename=\"NGOs.xlsx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20131206-14445-4cpor5>>, "commit"=>"Upload", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"lists"}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`File::extname`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-extname) returns extension name with leading `.`.

```
File.extname('a.xls')
# => ".xls"
```

And it does not lowercase it.

```
File.extname('a.XLS')
# => ".XLS"
```

So `if ..` line should be replaced with:

```
if File.extname(params[:contact_file].path.downcase) == '.xls'
```

If you also want ot filter `.xls`, `xlsx`, ..., Use [`String#end_with?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F):

```
if params[:contact_file].path.downcase.end_with?('.xls', '.xlsx')
```

Comment: I am now getting can't convert `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String`

Comment: @user2963716, Try `if File.extname(params[:contact_file].path.downcase) == '.xls'`

Comment: @user2963716, How about `if params[:contact_file].path.downcase.end_with?('.xls', '.xlsx')` ?

Comment: @user2963716, How about `if params[:contact_file].original_filename.downcase.end_with?('.xls', '.xlsx')` (change `path` with `orignal_filename`)

Answer (score 1):

falsetru's answer is great; I just wanted to add that you may also want to consider the fact that Excel files don't necessarily have .xls extensions.  In fact, the default extension for the current version of Excel is .xlsx.  So rather than doing a check for a single file extension like you are now.

```
File.extname( params[:contact_file] ) == '.xls'
```

You may want to consider instead checking against a collection. So instead you can do something like this for your check

```
['.xls','.xlsx', '.xlsb'].include? File.extname(params[:contact_file])
```

For a full list of Excel extensions so you can determine which ones you should be supporting you can take a look here.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-HP010014103.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`File.extname` returns `.xls` so the if needs to be

```
if ['.xls','.xlsx', '.xlsb', '.xlsm'].include? File.extname(params[:contact_file].path.downcase)
```

Comment: I am now getting can't convert `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String`

Comment: Can you try `params[:contact_file].path and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: @user2963716 The file uploaded is in the `.xlsx`. I have updated my answer to include that and all other excel formats.

Comment: Last Try: `File.extname(params[:contact_file].original_filename).downcase`

Answer (score 0):

#### Solve it via the browser

A simple way to solve it is via the field_tag helper. It has an `accept` option - where you can pass in mimetypes of the file(s) you want to accept. In my case, I want to accept: `xlsx` files, rather than `xls` files - which is a little older and kinda obsolete in 2024:

```
 <%= file_field_tag :part_list, accept: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" %>
```

However if you want `xls` consider the below solution:

```
 <%= file_field_tag :part_list, accept: "application/vnd.ms-excel" %>
```

In my use case, this will suffice. However, users can tamper with the html and still upload different file types. Consider carefully whether this will be a problem for your particular use case.

If so, consider the following options:

- prevent uploads via javascript, and then
- prevent uploads of black-listed files in your server.